# Managing external resources (similar to RAII in C++?)

Tags: opengl, common-lisp

In common lisp, what is the preferred way to manage external resources (sockets, filesystem handles, etc)?

I'm trying to make a simple opengl 2d platformer in common lisp.
The problem is I'm not quite sure how to track OpenGL textures (must be deleted with `glDeleteTextures` when they are no longer needed).

In C++ I preferred to use following scheme:

1. Make texture class
2. Make smart/weak pointers for that texture class
3. Store textures in map (dictionary/hashtable) that maps file names to weak pointers to textures.
4. When new textures are requested, look into map, and see if there's a non-null (nil) weak pointer available. If it is available, return existing object, otherwise load new texture.

However, I'm not quite sure how to port this scheme to common lisp, because:

1. There are no destructors.
2. There's garbage collector, and it seems my implementation (clozureCL on windows platform) supports finalizers, but as far as I can tell it is not recommended to use finalizers in common lisp because they're not deterministic.
3. The preferred way of managing resources using `(with-*` doesn't look suitable there, because resources can be shared, and loaded/unloaded in the middle of function call.

As far as I can tell, there are several approaches available:

1. Give up on automatic resource managment, and do it manually.
2. Implement something similar to C++ RAII, weakpointer and smartpointer using macros (this code probably doesn't work):

   ```
   (defclass destructible () ())

   (defmethod destroy ((obj destructible)) (print (format nil "destroy: ~A" obj)))

   (defparameter *destructible-classes-list* nil)

   (defmethod initialize-instance :after ((obj destructible) &key)
     (progn
         (push *destructible-classes-list* obj)
         (print (format nil "init-instance: ~A" obj))))

   (defmacro with-cleanup (&rest body)
     `(let ((*destructible-classes-list* nil))
       (progn ,@body (mapcar (lambda (x) (destroy x)) *destructible-classes-list*))))

   (defclass refdata (destructible)
     ((value :accessor refdata-value :initform nil)
      (ref :accessor refdata-ref :initform 0)
      (weakrefcount :accessor refdata-weakref :initform 0)))

   (defmethod incref ((ref refdata))
     (if ref (incf (refdata-ref ref))))

   (defmethod decref ((ref refdata))
     (if ref
       (progn (decf (refdata-ref ref))
        (if (<= (refdata-ref ref) 0) 
          (progn (destroy (refdata-value ref))
             (setf (refdata-value ref) nil))))))

   (defmethod incweakref ((ref refdata))
     (if ref (incf (refdata-weakref ref))))

   (defmethod decweakref ((ref refdata))
     (if ref (decf (refdata-weakref ref))))

   (defclass refbase (destructible) ((data :accessor refbase-data :initform nil)))

   (defmethod deref ((ref refbase))
     (if (and (refbase-data ref) (refdata-value (refbase-data ref)))
       (refdata-value (refbase-data ref))
       nil))

   (defclass strongref (refbase) ())

   (defclass weakref (refbase) ())

   (defmethod destroy :before ((obj strongref))
     (decref (refbase-data obj)))

   (defmethod destroy :before ((obj weakref))
     (decweakref (refbase-data obj)))

   (defmethod initialize-instance :after ((obj strongref) &key)
     (incref (refbase-data obj)))

   (defmethod initialize-instance :after ((obj weakref) &key)
     (incweakref (refbase-data obj)))
   ```

Is there a better way to do it?

**C++ Concepts Explanation:** [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with C++ to answer your question, but this project: http://common-lisp.net/project/trivial-garbage/ includes weak pointers and weak hash-tables, which looks like it may help. This may help as well: http://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/source/browse/trunk/lispbuilder-sdl/sdl/cffi-finalizers.lisp?r=426 (though `finalize` is now in trivial-garbage, not cffi)

Comment: @Lex: Does it mean there's no other way to do it? I've seen trivial-garbage, and while it is useful, it does not allow fine control. Also see *"but as far as I can tell it is not recommended to use finalizers in common lisp because they're not deterministic."*

Comment: I don't know enough about C++ to answer one way or the other. Just thought the code might help in your implementation.

Comment: @wvxvw: "(print (format nil" I'm just getting used to lisp, you know... "which is idk... have you really tested" The problem is that I need to manage objects that GC can't handle automatically (OpenGL objects - they can be freed only under specific conditions, etc), and those objects should exist for prolonged time. And of course, I want it to be done automatically. Judging by google search results, it seems this is a common problem for all GC languages - when you want something unusual to be GCd but only under certain conditions. Anything that isn't GL-related can be handled by GC, of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to handle a dynamic extent scope use [UNWIND-PROTECT](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_unwind.htm#unwind-protect). If the program leaves that scope - normally or on error - the clean-up form is called. Just deallocate there or do whatever you want.

Sometimes Lisps use some kind of 'resource' mechanism to keep track of used and unused objects. Such a library provides fast allocation from a pool, allocating, initialization, deallocation, mapping of resourced object. CLIM defines a primitive version: [Resources](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLIM/html/climuser-334.htm#pgfId-44509). CCL has a similar primitive version of it.

In a Lisp with 'timers', you can run a function periodically which looks for 'objects' to deallocate. In CCL you can use a thread which sleeps for a certain time using `PROCESS-WAIT`.

A bit about your coding style:

- `FORMAT` can directly output to a stream, no PRINT needed
- `(defmethod foo ((e bar)) (if e ...))` : the `IF` makes no sense. `e` will always be an object.
- many `PROGN` are not needed. Where needed, it could be removed when `IF` is replaced by  `WHEN`.

Comment: That's pretty close to what I've been looking for, thank you.

Comment: "A bit about your coding style" Thanks for the tips, but I"m new to this (I think this is either 2nd or 3rd lisp program I've written?) so I guess coding style will improve evenetually - when I get more experience...

Comment: @SigTerm checkout Clozure Common Lisp's 'with-autorelease-pool' macro as a concrete example. It uses the unwind-protect technique Rainer mentions here.